Identify a medieval film where the hero has claws
This was a live action film made, probably, in the 60s or 70s.  It is set in a pseudo medieval world but I do not recall there being magic.
Towards the beginning of the film the hero is trying to escape from a castle with some people and they exit though a trap door which he holds shut from underneath.  The villain has acid or something poured onto the trap door and it destroys the hero's hands.
They escape and the hero goes to see someone who makes him claws to replace his hands. He then heads back to get revenge.

You forgot to mention it's also Turkish. :) This sounds like Lion Man (AKA Aslan Adam from 1975).

When the king is murdered, his baby son and heir is hidden in the forest where he is abducted and raised by a pride of lions. As an adult he uses his beastly strength and claw-like hands to take revenge against the new king and his armies.

Both scenes are there: He hangs from a trap door and has acid poured on his hands, and later acquires metal claws.


This might very well be Army of Darkness. 
It's a (somewhat odd) comedy about a guy from present time getting sucked in some kind of wormhole, where he gets warped to the middle ages. There he is considered an enemy of the people who find him, and thrown into a deep pit. After getting out of the pit, he ends up having to help protect the town against an army of 'walking dead'.
Your description doesn't match this movie completely, but close enough if you ask me. About the 'claws' you mention, he somehow loses one hand early in the movie and he attaches a chainsaw to his arm.
P.s. fun fact: If you're a gamer, Duke Nukem uses many quotes from this movie.

i dont think its army of darkness he loses his hand on Evil dead 2 itself.

I have no idea what you're talking about, but in the beginning of Army of Darkness, Ash (the main character) has got both hands. Then he get bitten by a zombie (i believe), and cuts off his right hand to prevent the infection from spreading throughout his body.

@poepje the bit you're talking about is a recap of the previous film as mentioned by Dredd. Army of Darkness is the third and final installment in The Evil Dead trilogy

Oh, I see. I never heard of 'Evil Dead' (didn't say it was an Evil Dead movie in the title) and the movie didn't make it clear that it was a recap of the previous part. But I understand why the beginning of the movie was so weird and fast now :)

Nah it is not this. I have seen this movie many times and am a big fan of the trilogy. The film I am referring to was shot decades earlier.  Thanks for trying to help though! :-)
